# Sprouting turtles spaced at least one patch apart

Tags: simulation, netlogo

Is there a way that I can sprout turtles given that they have at least one empty patch between other turtles?

Answer (score 2):

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches [ if not any? neighbors with [any? turtles-here]  [ sprout 1]]
end
```